# How to get the percentage change with intervals on Microsoft Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

So I have a dataset of monthly stock returns from January 2000 until today for six different stock indices. At the bottom of the page, I want to show the yearly return for each year as a percentage change from the previous year (i.e. I want to create a table with one column having '2001', '2002' and the other column having '8%', '-4%' etc. What command would I use?

In addition to this, is there any way to create a formula such that when the first cell calculates the return across the year 2000, the second cell calculates 2001, third cell calculates 2002 etc? So I don't have to manually type the cell ranges for each year and avoid human error.

I have attached an image of my dataset, if anyone could write the excel input or help me figure out how to write it I would appreciate it very much! The return for 2000 would show in cell b256, 2001 in b257 etc

[Index Returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqDle.png)

[Table which I want to show the returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plmFH.png)

Comment: Thought I'd write out the command I need in another way so that it makes sense - I want to calculate the percentage change from december 31st of year n to december 31st of year n+1 for every single year for the stocks in image 1 and place it in the table format of image 2. Is there a command that would let me do this, as well as dragging it down so that it works for all years?

Answer (score 0):

For years 2001 and later, you can do the following. For 2000, there is no value provided for 12/31/1999 to compare it to:

```
=(XLOOKUP(DATE($A257,12,31),$A$2:$A$253,B$2:B$253,,-1)/XLOOKUP(DATE($A257-1,12,31),$A$2:$A$253,B$2:B$253,,-1))-1
```

That's the formula for B257. It will copy to the right and down and succeed in all cells for the 20 rows and 6 columns.

It takes the formula ( ( 2001 - 2000 ) / 2000 ) and using a mite bit of algebra gives ( 2001 / 2000 ) - 1.

The "tricks" are producing a date from the year informatiuon in the %Return region by using `DATE()` to get the very last day of the year involved which `XLOOKUP()` can use in an "Equal to or less than" match to find the last date reproted for the appropriate year. And subtracting 1 from that year to find the same value for the previous year to drive the division and then judicious use of the absolute and relative referencing to keep the lookup using column A while the row changes and the `Return_Array`'s column being able to change as you copy it to the right but making sure the rows do not change as you copy down because they specify the whole used portion of the column every time, not just one cell, so they should not change.